# CSS clamp rule to generate %/vw values for margin property?

Tags: css

I'm having one of those moments where my brain is getting tied in a knot.

I'd like a `div` to have a `margin` of `10%` when the viewport is 900px or wider, and `1%` when it's 450px or narrower.  And for it to linearly interpolate between those two points, so 675px viewport would give `5.5%` margin, for instance.

```
margin: clamp(1%, ???, 10%);
```

I can't for the life of me work out what to put in here.  Those two points give a straight-line equation (I think!) of `margin = viewportWidth/50 - 8`... but where do I go from here..?

```
margin: clamp(1%, 100vw/50 - 8vw, 10%);
```

nope, that makes no sense, it'll always be `-6vw`.

I think maybe it needs to be

```
margin: clamp(1%, 100vw / 50px - 8vw, 10%);
```

but Devtools (in Edge) complains that's an invalid property value.  I can guess that the browser converts vw to pixels, so divides (say) `800px` by `50px` and gets `16`.  Not `16%` or `16vw`, but `16`.  How do I change that?

Someone put me out of my misery, please.

Answer (score -2):

OK, sorted.

```
margin: clamp(1%, 19% - 81px, 10%);
```

testing:

```
900px:  900 * .19 - 81  =     90  =   10% of 900
450px:  450 * .19 - 81  =    4.5  =    1% of 450

500px:  500 * .19 - 81  =     14  =  2.8% of 500
675px:  675 * .19 - 81  =  47.25  =    7% of 675
850px:  850 * .19 - 81  =   80.5  =  9.5% of 850
```

ok, so 675 doesn't end up as 5.5% margin, but good enough.  And although I kinda understand WHY it doesn't, I struggle to put it into words.  Someone edit this answer please and explain

How did I get there?

Two points (900, 10%) and (450, 1%).  Convert them to pixels, crucially.  (900, 90) and (450, 4.5).  I realised the middle term I was looking for was going to be of the form `{b}% - {b}px`, so made two equations from the points I had:

```
(1) 450/100y - x = 4.5
(2) 900/100y - x =  90
```

solve for x & y:

```
(1) becomes: x = 4.5y - 4.5
substitute into (2): 9y - 4.5y + 4.5 = 90
reduces down to: 4.5y = 85.5
gives: y = 19
meaning: x = 4.5 * 19 - 4.5 = 81

y = 19
x = 81
```